# (Mysql Error: #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint) for my program

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

There is a problem to create a table with foreign_key. Can you please help me to solve it.
The error is:
SQL query:

ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT FK_users FOREIGN KEY ( groupname_id ) REFERENCES groups( group_id ) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE ;

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` (
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_level` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `groupname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`),
    KEY idx_groupname (groupname)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=64 ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` char(100) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `groupname_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=46 ;



ALTER TABLE users
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_users
FOREIGN KEY (groupname_id) REFERENCES groups(group_id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that `groupname_id` and `group_id` aren't the same type.  One is unsigned, while the other is not.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: are both tables empty?

Comment: mrjink@I made groupname_id and group_id as the same but it didn't work again.

Comment: Gooner@Yes both are empty.

Comment: This is the same but works perfectly:     CREATE TABLE employee (
id smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
firstname varchar(30),
lastname varchar(30),
birthdate date,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
KEY idx_lastname (lastname)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE borrowed (
ref int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
employeeid smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
book varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY (ref)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;ALTER TABLE borrowed
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_borrowed
FOREIGN KEY (employeeid) REFERENCES employee(id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;

Comment: then remove the `unsigned` clause from the `create table` of `users`

Comment: Gooner@I did it but the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the problem is that `groupname_id` on the `users` table is unsigned, while the `group_id` on the `groups` table is signed.

It was a hunch, so I tested it, and just now successfully added and altered these tables on my `test` database.  MySQL 5.6.16 on Windows.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` (
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_level` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `groupname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`),
    KEY idx_groupname (groupname)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=64 ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` char(100) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `groupname_id` int(11) NOT NULL, -- should be signed, not unsigned, just like above
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=46 ;



ALTER TABLE users
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_users
FOREIGN KEY (groupname_id) REFERENCES groups(group_id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks. I had too drop tables and then test your code. That's what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your groupname_id column is unsigned. Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` (
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_level` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `groupname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`group_id`),
    KEY idx_groupname (groupname)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=64 ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` char(100) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `groupname_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=46 ;



ALTER TABLE users
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_users
FOREIGN KEY (groupname_id) REFERENCES groups(group_id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: The same error: SQL query:

ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT FK_users FOREIGN KEY ( groupname_id ) REFERENCES groups( group_id ) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE ;


MySQL said: Documentation

#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Is there any notice about database that maybe I don't know about?

Comment: What do you mean by notice about database?

Comment: Thanks. I had to drop tables and then test your code to work and I didn't do that. I works perfectly.